# Global variable and addEventlistener

Tags: javascript, global-variables, addeventlistener

Here is the problem: I would like to have global variable X which takes value of alpha. With code below, value for X in console is always zero.

```
var X = 0; 

window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, true);

function handleOrientation(event) {
    var alpha = Math.round(event.alpha);  
    X = alpha;
}

console.log(X);
```

EDIT: 
I wanted to do something like

```
var X = 0; 

window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, true);

function handleOrientation(event) {
    var alpha = Math.round(event.alpha);  
    X = alpha;
}

function f(x){ return x*x }

f(X);
```

Now I understand that I have to put f(X) within function handleOrientation. I guess there is not other way around?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with your code, but you don't print anything out when the event fires or any time after the event fires. How are you verifying that `X` remains `0` after the event fires?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the value of `X` before it changes. Here's the order in which your code runs:

1. Create a function called `handleOrientation`. (Why first? Because creating the functions described by function *declarations* is one of the very first things done upon entry to a scope.)
2. Declare a variable called `X`. (First not only because it's at the top, but because creating variables declared with `var` is one of the very first things done upon entry to a scope, soon after processing function declarations.)
3. Assign `0` to `X`. (This is the first step-by-step code that runs.)
4. Call `addEventListener` on `window`.
5. Output `X` to the console.
6. (If and when the `deviceorientation` event is triggered on `window`) Update the value of `X`.

Instead, use the value *after* it changes:

```
var X = 0; 

window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, true);

function handleOrientation(event) {
    var alpha = Math.round(event.alpha);  
    X = alpha;
    console.log(X);
}
```

Or:

```
var X = 0; 

window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, true);

function handleOrientation(event) {
    var alpha = Math.round(event.alpha);  
    X = alpha;
    doSomethingWithX();
}

function doSomethingWithX() {
    console.log(X);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I understand what you are saying but when I create another function, let's say function f(a){..} which takes X as a argument I always have f(0) because X=0 outside of function handleOrientation.

Comment: @Puibo: I'm afraid that's not clear. If you give an example of what you want to do, I can show you how to do it. If you want to use `X` in other functions, you can; they'll see its value as of when they run. If they run before the event handler fires, they'll see `0`; if they run after it fires, they'll see the value assigned by the event handler. The issue is timing.

Comment: Ok, this solves my problem completely. I have only one more question. There is no possible way to put f(X) outside of handleOrientation function (look at my edited post)?

Comment: @Puibo: It can be outside of it. What it can't be is *before* it. That is, you can use `X` anywhere at all in your script (because it's a global), but it's **when** you use it that matters. Your original code was using it *before* it got its value from the event handler. You have to use it afterward. The best way to do that is to trigger something from your event handler, since you know the value has been updated at that point.

Comment: @ T.J. Now, I understand it. Thank you for your help.